# Zooming-in a page on the Android browser creates a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, responsive-design, android-browser

I'm trying to create the simplest possible portable page that will display on all browser widths. So I created http://itia.ntua.gr/~anthony/tmp/, which is the kind of HTML we were using 20 years ago. No CSS, no fixed-width stuff, no javascript, just a heading and paragraphs. You can make your browser as wide or narrow as you wish, zoom in and out as much as you want, and it will adapt perfectly.

On my smartphone, Firefox works perfectly with that page. However, the pre-installed browser (I'm using Cyanogenmod, I guess the preinstalled browser is the Android browser) initially displays the page too zoomed-out. If I zoom-in, the text wraps, but then the visible area is only part of the viewport, which can scroll horizontally, showing empty space on the right (very annoying because you can accidentally scroll horizontally when you are trying to scroll vertically).

[An image is worth 100 words http://itia.ntua.gr/~anthony/tmp/android-browser-simple-page.png](http://itia.ntua.gr/~anthony/tmp/android-browser-simple-page.png)

How can I create a simple page that can work properly on the Android browser? Preferably without needing to become a responsive design expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

between **head** tag.

More information :

- http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html
- http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html